# can't get Consumer ID after uploading RSA keys

Tags: walmart-api

This is my first time trying to access the Walmart API.  I created my account and followed the onboarding steps but I can't get the Dashboard to generate "consumer ID" for me.

I have created my application, and click on “Upload/Update public key”.  I copy-pasted two RSA public keys into the field; one for Staging, and one for Production.  However it never creates the “Consumer ID” for my application.  Can you see my dashboard entry in your system?

Why am I not issued a consumer ID after uploading my public keys?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the issue will be either
the public key is invalid (or)
if you already have consumer id and trying to update with the same public key then there will be an issue (or)
if you have copied public key along with any white spaces (or)
if you are trying to upload private key by mistake

Regards,
Firdos
IO Support